# Mounting hfs volume under MacOS Catalina

Tags: mount, qemu, macos-catalina, hfs

I'm running MacOS X Catalina. To be able to connect to an HFS volume created by QEMU I tried

```
sudo mount -t hfs qemuhdd.raw /tmp/os9vm
```

I got the following error:

```
GetMasterBlock: Error 25 getting block size
GetMasterBlock: Error 25 getting block size
mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
mount_hfs: Block device required
mount: /private/tmp/os9vm failed with 1
```

This is exactly the command given in [this article](http://blog.labcellar.com/2017/10/01/emuler-mac-os-9-avec-qemu/), written in October 2017, so I can only guess that MacOS X does not allow mounting to HFS volumes anymore. Any hints on what I can do?

Comment: This is really not my strong suit, but I'm guessing that you can't mount to a protected System location. Why don't you just let it mount to /Volumes, like normal?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work: `sudo mount -t hfs qemuhdd.raw /Volumes/qemuhdd/
GetMasterBlock: Error 25 getting block size
GetMasterBlock: Error 25 getting block size
mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
mount_hfs: Block device required
mount: /Volumes/qemuhdd failed with 1`
Same problem…

Comment: Hmm… It's going to be that the boot drive is protected, even from 'root' or sudo from being written to. Maybe have a look at https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout/ to see what's protected & what you might be able to use. It's not that the disk is HFS, it's where you're trying to mount it.